# How can i extract data point value from tooltips of scatter plot?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I' m trying to get the `x` and `y` values of a scatter point.  I simply want to extract data points values (`x = 280` and `y = 164`) when I click on the data point on scatter plot.

[image]

Also, I cannot use chart events because of the dashboard.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

When you hoover over point it should write you Series name and (X,Y)